# Действия по конкретным словам в AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

Есть fragment на ней два AutoCompleteTextView и Button, у меня AutoCompleteTextView заполнен из текстовых ресурсов, но для примера я напишу так допустим он заполнен массивом {"1","2","3"}. Как сделать так, чтобы если пользователь вводил в AutoCompleteTextView 1 при нажатии на кнопку выполнялись такие-то действия, 2 - другие. Или так нельзя?

Мой код тут 2 AutoCompleteTextView

```
public class FragmentSearchRoute extends Fragment {

    AutoCompleteTextView autotxt1,autotxt2;
    String [] ar;
    List<String> arList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.fr3);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_route, container, false);
        autotxt1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autotv1);
        autotxt2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autotv2);
        ar = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stops);
        arList  = Arrays.asList(ar);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arList);
        autotxt1.setAdapter(adapter);
        autotxt2.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, задача такая: нужно, чтобы после ввода строки и клика на кнопку, выполнялось определенное действие (для каждой введенной строки разное).

Достаточно просто повесить на кнопку `OnClickListener` и при клике проверять, какой текст был введен и выбирать действие:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = autotxt1.getText().toString();
        switch (text) {
            case "1": ...
            case "2": ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все правильно вы поняли буду пробовать.

Comment: А можно это как нибудь через оператор  If сделать у меня просто две AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: Делайте через if) Можно было и не спрашивать)

Comment: так у меня вопрос как сделать

Comment: А не лучше разобраться как работает if-else, прежде чем лезть в андроид?) Писать код за вас здесь никто не будет

Comment: Блин ну хоть направьте на русло нужное, как вы сделали с примером со switch пожалуйста

Comment: Ну не хотят люди учиться... `if (text.equals("1")) { ... } else if (text.equals("2)) { ... } else...`